# Is IMAP (un)subscribe meant to work across mail clients?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, imap, subscription

I read my IMAP-mail on different computers/mail clients. I wanted to unsubscribe from the majority of my folders in Outlook. Later, I noticed that on another computer, where I use Thunderbird, I was also unsubscribed from those folders as well. This is not what I wanted (at all), so I subscribed again under Thunderbird. The effect was that I also got subscribed again under Outlook.

So I guess this means (un)subscribing to IMAP folders is an account-coupled thing, not a per-client thing. Is there a way to achieve (un)subscribing per client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMAP subscriptions are handled and stored by the IMAP server, so your subscriptions will be the same regardless of which client you use. So I doubt you're going to find a client that can unsubscribe only for itself.

Perhaps check out the SU question [What does it mean to "subscribe" to an IMAP folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/61585/what-does-it-mean-to-subscribe-to-an-imap-folder) for more info.